# Why can't I override my views theme template files?

Tags: views, theming

I am using D7. I am using one of the template file names suggested in the theming information in the view. Putting that template file in my theme templates folder. saving it and clearing the cache. The .tpl.php does not seem to be recognized and/or overwrite the default file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: subtle naming errors can be brutal, give us some more specifics, eg, the exact name you are giving it, the name of the view, etc, and maybe we can shed more light on it...

Comment: I am using the name as suggested by them views module itself, copied and pasted from the "theme information" section

Comment: @A_funs, Jimajamma asked for the exact name.

Comment: @NikhilMohan Thanks for that brilliant insight ; )

Comment: @A_funs, If you expect answer, give respect. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you use the Rescan button in the Theme: Information dialog. Also, be aware that pasting names not carefully enough can put white space in front of the file name. You wont see the spaces in FileZilla or TC, but it can leave your file unrecognized. So watch out when pasting.

Comment: indeed, I've pasted a filename with a space at the front many a time :)

Comment: And the only way to successfully bust such a guy is via cmd ftp using DELE " FILENAME" - with quotes. Have you found another way around?

Comment: This ultimately lead me to the issue, which was that I wasn't saving the view, after the scan and the template files were found, I assumed the templates would be used by default similar to how other templates are called by default in drupal if they override core templates. I didn't know the implementation of these view templates was any different.